# Strange behaviour of timeslice in Sumo Logic

Tags: sumo, sumologic

I have this query in sumo:

```
_sourceCategory=my_product
| timeslice 1h
| count by _timeslice
```

In my aggregates list I have a 1h difference between the data:

[image]

but in my graph I have a 15 mins segment like this:

[image]

So my question is: where does this 15 min segments come from?

Answer (score 2):

Every search result includes a histogram that shows the *number* of results over time -- this is what your screenshot shows.

The actual results of your query will be shown below that, in the Messages/Aggregates area. Choose the Bar Chart visualisation to see the search results with your hour timeslice.
https://help.sumologic.com/Search/Search-Query-Language/Search-Operators/timeslice